# Signal value classification by limits from database

Tags: sql, classification

Given some signals I need to find out the state of a machine with configured min and max limits.
I plan to build a table with the following structure (and example data)

```
| StateID | SignalID | min | max |  
|---------|----------|-----|-----|  
|    1    |    1     |  1  |  2  |  
|    1    |    3     |  2  |  3  |  
|    2    |    2     |  0  |  4  |  
|    3    |    2     |  5  |  9  |
```

thus I can find possible states by those lines valid (in the sense that the value of SignalID is between min and max).
The intersection of valid states for all signal should then result in the correct state (assuming the table is complete in that way). But - as for some states maybe there is no affinity to a given signal - I think one must first iterize over the states - what somehow seems to be inefficient, or?
Some examples from the given table above (where fulfilled means, the SignalValue is between min and max):

- (1,2,3) -> 1 (row 1 and 2 are fulfilled) or -> 2 (row 3 fulfilled)
- (2,9,2) -> 1 (row 1 and 2 are fulfilled) or -> 3 (row 4 fulfilled)
- (3,1,3) -> 2 (only row 3 fulfilled)
- (3,8,2) -> 3 (only row 4 fulfilled)

Starting over I have some questions:

1. Can I change something in the table structure (or logic) to optimize it?
2. How can I handle a state which is NOT depending on a signal WITHOUT adding a line with min=-infinity and max=infinity for that
   state?
3. As the number of states and signals is dynamic - how to do the corresponding query efficient? Can the intersection (of a dynamic
   count of results) be done in SQL?

Thanks for any ideas and help.

Comment: "Some examples from the given table above" - nope, you've lost me. I've no idea what the triples inside the brackets are meant to be.

Comment: I second that. The table data doesn't even contain a single `8`. But the last triple does.

Comment: Hi - sorry for that unclear situation. The triple values are corresponding to values of SignalID. For example (3,8,2) means SignalID1=3,SignalID2=8,SignalID3=2. Line 1 is false, Line 2 is true, Line 3 is false and Line 4 is true. Only all requirements for State3 is fulfilled. Clear now?

Comment: "Clear now?" - No, not really. Why are the lines true or false? What is the criteria for this? And what does the numbers mean after the triple? What are those three signal IDs in the triple?

Comment: I *think* you want to replace line with "table row" and assume a row's `StateID` is valid iff the equation `row.min <= row.SignalID <= row.max` holds. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes @mabi, this is it - I thaught it was clear by the text. Sorry for my inprecise description.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm going to answer what I think your question was, not what you actually asked. So please clarify further if I didn't get what you're trying to do.

You're storing two different facts, but you only gave an example for one. I'm assuming you want to record A) allowed states and B) observed states, ie:

```
CREATE TABLE valid_states (
  state_nbr integer not null,
  signal_nbr integer,
  signal_min integer,
  signal_max integer,

  PRIMARY KEY (state_nbr, signal_nbr)
);

CREATE TABLE observed_signals (
  signal_nbr integer primary key,
  signal_value integer not null
);
```

You can then query for "observed valid state(s)" by selecting from both:

```
SELECT s.state_nbr, o.signal_nbr 
  FROM valid_states AS s LEFT JOIN observed_signals AS o ON s.signal_nbr = o.signal_nbr 
  WHERE o.signal_value BETWEEN s.signal_min AND s.signal_max 
    OR (s.signal_min IS NULL AND o.signal_value <= s.signal_max)
    OR (s.signal_max IS NULL AND o.signal_value >= s.signal_min)
    OR (s.signal_min IS NULL AND s.signal_max IS NULL);
```

Well, there're probably ways to write that query more effectively, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your lines! Indeed I did not mention the observed_signals as they are not my problem. You answered my question just the way, I would do it - if there will not be any other answers here. Especially I'm interested in efficient solutions and further with you (very nice) example take my values (3,8,2) the result should only show state_nbr=3 as not all state_nbr=1 conditions are met. Additionally I'm not sure if there is maybe another idea for a table structure to solve my problem.